# htaccess ignore rewrite to api url

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, kirby

I’ve build the front end of a site using angular and have created the cms through Kirby. Kirby allows you to build a json api from the structure you create with the cms, [like so](http://getkirby.com/blog/json).

What I’m trying to do now is use the api provided by Kirby which is:

```
address.com/projects/api
```

within my angular app. I’m using html5 and htaccess to rewrite my urls so I dont need to use a hash within the url and page refreshes on a subpage get redirected to the appropriate angular view.

```
address.com/work
address.com/about
address.com/single-project
```

my htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html
```

Kirby requires its own htaccess to serve pages also, so my question... Is it possible to allow access to my json template at address.com/projects/api and still preserve the angular clean urls?

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to ignore /projects/api? Then you can do this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/projects/api [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

Comment: I got a ‘Not Found’ when going to projects/api with this htaccess code

Comment: Well is projects/api a real location or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more exclusions in your negative `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index|projects/api) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it shortly after posting #facepalm.
The additional line that did the trick for anyone in the same or similar situation

```
RewriteRule (api) index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but none of the above solved my problem.

My current .htaccess is as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.app.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

my API folder path is http://www.app.mydomain/api